# What size nipple should I use for granny bike rim?

Tags: rims, wheel-building, nipples

I am going to build my first wheel using the Ryde V38 rim (Westwood type). 
The shop where I ordered the rim, says it has 5.5 mm spoke holes.

The nipples that come with the regular 2.34 mm (13 g) spokes are specified to have a 5.9 mm nipple head diameter.

It seems like that is a rather small overlap, so I am wondering if I should use "large head nipples" (7 mm) instead?

Answer (score 2):

5.5mm spoke holes sounds ridiculously large and it would not surprise me if that's not correct. Ryde don't mention it on their [generic V38 page](http://www.ryde.nl/en/products?product=22) nor do "Flying Pigeon" on [their Westwood listing](http://flyingpigeonla.myshopify.com/products/ryde-v38-westwood-profile-rim) but they do suggest 2.0mm spokes. No mention of needing large head nipples though.

If you can try the large head in the rim before buying definitely do that. Otherwise I'd be tempted to wait and see, since if you need the large head nipples you'll need to buy them separately anyway so you only lose time by waiting to see if you need them.

Comment: [This page](http://en.hollandbikeshop.com/bicycle-wheels/bicycle-rims/bicycle-rim-20-inch/ryde-rim-v38-20-x-1-75-36-hole-black/) mentions 5,5 mm holes, but in the image the holes just don't look that big. But they say "DV"; what does that mean?

Comment: [Amazon UK has someone selling them](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Spoke-nipple-M3-set-piece/dp/B0050GL4Q8) who says they're 5mm/7mm in diameter which seems huge to me.

Comment: I guess DV means Dunlop Valve.

Comment: I also wondered why the Ryde website didn't say anything about it, it it's a special thing. In their PDF catalogue, some of the other Westwood type rims are mentioned to have the 5.5 mm spoke holes though.